# SQL- how to sum up the last x days number (days are not consecutive)

Tags: sql, sum

I have a table which looks like

```
ds             Transaction 
2022-01-01      1          
2022-01-02      2          
2022-01-07      1          
2022-01-08      1
```

I want to sum up the last 3 days numbers on each date.
My original thought is to use window function like

```
SUM(Transaction) OVER (ORDER BY
ds ASC ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

It didn't work, because the date is not consecutive. the expected result should be like this:

```
Date            Transaction 
2022-01-01      1          
2022-01-02      3          
2022-01-07      1          
2022-01-08      2
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RANGE` instead of `ROWS` in your window function:

```
select ds,
SUM(Transact) OVER (ORDER BY
ds ASC RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '2' DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as Transaction
from table_name;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=91bc03b4d7d3fd8788b9cb2a2b286fe2)

Comment: Thank you so much! but when i use "range". it has syntax error: Window frame start value type must be INTEGER or BIGINT(actual interval day to second

Comment: @zoez what RDBMS are you using? Could you reproduce the error in the *fiddle* link?

Comment: i used presto.i can run the fiddle link without error

Comment: @zoez I'm sorry I'm not familiar with presto.